# reexport - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: babeljs

There is such a file. That imports from API and exports at once.

```js
export { extractValue, parse, parseCommand }  from './parser'
export { Manager, EVENTS } from './manager'
export { runCLI, runCommand, bootstrapCommandManager } from './cli'
```

I receive an error:

```sh
export { extractValue, parse, parseCommand }  from './parser'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

There is my babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}]],
    plugins: [
      ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'],
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', {'legacy': true}],
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from']
    ]
  };
```

`@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from` does not help.

Answer (score 0):

It did not compile files from node_modules directory. An ignore rule had to be set.
It works
Variant A babel-node

```sh
npx babel-node --ignore="/node_modules\/(?\!console-command-manager)/"  --config-file ./babel.config.js ./src/index.js
```

I fault to move --ignore argument into ./babel.config.js

Variant B
Node executtion with -r runner.js
Execution

```sh
node -r ./runner.js src/index.js
```

Runner

```js
const config = require('./babel.config.js')
console.log(config)
require("@babel/register")({
  extensions: ['.js'],
  ignore: [
    /node_modules[\\/](?!console-command-manager)/
  ],
  ...config
});
```